# How do I set up a wireless router with two different passwords such that there are two different behaviors based on which password you use

Tags: networking

I would like one password to enable full access to a network, shared computers, NAS's etc.
And then another password that just is able to see shared computers.
And then maybe another one (i know most routers have this) a guest password that just enables the internet, and nothing else.

thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, even consumer products like the Apple AirPort Express base station can provide a main network with access to everything, including "internal" resources like printers and NASes and shared computers, plus a "guest network" that only has access to the Internet.

The thing that's really unique about your request is this "in-between" network you want, that has *some, limited* access to internal resources. I wouldn't be surprised if one of the Linux-based aftermarket firmware distros like DD-WRT, OpenWRT, Tomato, etc. could do what you want. You'd want to find one that supports publishing multiple SSIDs, each on a separate VLAN. Then you could configure routing between those VLANs, moderated by firewall rules that decide which devices and services are reachable from which VLAN.

Comment: While I'm also sure DD-WRT can do this (with 2 SSID's, not sure about 3), I haven't actually tried it myself.  Anyway, [here's a write up to get you started](http://www.pennock.nl/dd-wrt/Multiple_BSSIDs.html).